Where to rent a remote virtual machine with GUI operating system and a web browser for no more than 5$?
I want to rent a remote virtual machine with basically just a GUI operating system and a web browser.

I don't care if the GUI is Linux/Windows/anything else.
I don't care if the plan is hourly or monthly.
I want to pay no more than 5$ (five USD) a month in any situation, and to be able to cancel the plan at any time.

I ran a Google search with a query such as web browser as a service and found nothing suitable.
Where to rent a remote virtual machine with GUI operating system and a web browser?

I've done some reseach. And while i couldn't find any at the price you requested, i found https://shadow.tech/shadowpc/offers where you can rent a pc a machine with the following config:

GPU NVIDIA® GTX 1080 (P5000)
Intel Xeon™ (up to 3,1 GHz) 4 vCores
6 GB RAM
C:\ 256GB SSD
D:\ Up to 5TB of HDD
Windows 10 Home
1Gb/s down Bandwidth

As of today 19/12/2024 their price stated on their website is $19.99/month without taxes
